# How to set external links to PDF?

Tags: c#, itext

I have made a PDF report from html page using iTextSharp, this is how the report looks like:

`Id| Name| Date      | Message
  1| Test| 01/01/2017| test message
  2| Test| 01/01/2017| test message`

Now want to add link to each id, for example when i click id 1, it browser should have URL`www.google.com`, on click of 2 it has URL of facebook.

Is this scenario possible to achieve using itextsharp?

NOTE: I am having report in html format and converting it to PDF using iTextSharp.

Comment: Try by using anchor tag, while creating PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using HTML Anchor tag while creating HTML,

```
<a href="{URL}"> Click Here </a>
```